# error in hadoop path while using pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have had pig and hadoop working. But for unknown reasons it stopped working for the very next file. After all the reinstallation of hadoop and formatting, I have encountered a new problem. I cant copy my input file to hadoop:

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/pig/tutorial/pigtmp/bigdata.txt /user/hduser
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -ls /user/hduser
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup   10485760 2013-06-28 20:48 /user/hduser
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$
```

Can anyone please suggest what should I do? I don't have a good knowledge of hadoop or pig.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file has been copied to HDFS, to the file you named: `/home/hduser`. The `ls` output you list shows the file being around 10MB in size.

Now i presume what you were looking for was for the file to exist in the folder `/home/hduser`. I'm also guessing that this folder didn't exist prior to you running the `-copyFromLocal` command - in this case hadoop will copy to the named file. If the named file was a directory, then hadoop will copy to a file inside that directory (with the file having the same name as the local copy).

So to fix this you need to make sure the folder exists before you do the `-copyFromLocal` fs command:

```
# Delete the current file you have:
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -rmr /user/hduser

# create the hdusers home directory
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -mkdir /user/hduser

# Copy the txt file from local to the hduser folder in hdfs
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/pig/tutorial/pigtmp/bigdata.txt /user/hduser/

# Now the ls should show the file
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -ls /user/hduser/
```

Comment: its odd that i tried this before as i also noticed that my 10MB file was actually written in '/user/hduser' bt nothing worked. But this time it did. :D Thanks a lot.